# Django Cookiecutter upgrade best practice

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, cookiecutter-django

I built an application using  cookiecutter-django by @pydanny back in May,
docker-compose was used for both dev and production environments and it's running very well,

Now I have a requirement for asynchronous tasks and I want to use Celery,
I did not choose celery when using the cookiecutter tool way back at the beginning,

What's the best way to integrate celery into my project ?
Also noting that I will probably take this opportunity to upgrade docker-compose from version 2 to 3, bring mailgun, Django etc. to the latest versions

Is it too messy to integrate to a live project ?
Should I just create a new project using the cookiecutter tool ?
Not too sure how to approach this so any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by creating a new project from scratch using cookiecutter-django, this time including celery, flower etc. for async tasks. I then migrated my code to the new project. It didn't take too long, you just need to be careful when migrating that you don't miss anything.